# Separate references of appendix from the references of the rest writing

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

I want to make sure the references in the appendix are separated from the main body making them more accessible to the reader. How can you make it in LaTex?

```
\\\\\\\ Conceptual example \\\\\\\\\\

Main writing is here [1] where I have references [2]. Good morning [3] :)

[1] ref1
[2] ref2
[3] ...

Appendices

My appendices are related to the main writing but it is easier for the reader if mililons of referencees here [I]...[III] do not make reading of main writing less accessible -- so I want to have two different reference blocks so now the reference block of appendices starting below with good morning tea cookie smile to everyone :)

[I] ...
[II] ...
[III] ...
```

Comment: Are you using `\appendix` before the appendixes?

Comment: @Sigur no, I am using \begin{appendices}\section{hello}...\end{appendices}. Thank you for question.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with *separated from the main body*. Try to add a minimal example. Do you want to start a new page (`\newpage`) before the references?

Comment: @Sigur let's keep this question specific: only to entity separation of references to different blocks called main writing and appendices, added a conceptual example. Does it clarifies?

Comment: It will depend how you are inserting the references. You can use `thebibliography` many times. I think that what you want is multiple references.